# Julia - Random number in different intervals

Tags: random, julia

Hello

I would like create an array with numbers from different intervals.

For example, with the following code:

```
using Distributions

A = rand(Uniform(1,10),1,20)
```

"A" contains 20 numbers between 1 and 10.

I would like create "B" where "B" contains 20 numbers between 1 and 4, or between 6 and 10 but not between 4 and 6.

Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for general usecase, you want to make sure that the new probability you're sampling from is still a uniform one, albeit spread across non-connecting ranges.

I hacked together a function that produces a new uniform distribution from multiple disconnected uniform distributions:

```
using Distributions


function general_uniform(distributions...)

    all_dists = [distributions...]
    sort!(all_dists, by = D -> minimum(D))

    # make sure ranges are non overlapping
    @assert all(map(maximum, all_dists)[1:end-1] .<= map(minimum, all_dists)[2:end])

    dist_legths = map(D -> maximum(D) - minimum(D), all_dists)
    ratios = dist_legths ./ sum(dist_legths)

    return MixtureModel(all_dists, Categorical(ratios))
end
```

Then you can sample from this like this:

```
B = rand(general_uniform(Uniform(1,4), Uniform(6,10)),1,20)
```

This will give you a uniform distribution even if your ranges don't have the same length. For example:

```
general_uniform(Uniform(0,1), Uniform(1,10))
```

Will sample from range 0-1 with probability of 0.1 and from range 1-10 with probability of 0.9.

For example, the following gives a number around 5:

```
mean(rand(general_uniform(Uniform(0,9), Uniform(9,10)),1000))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
numbers = []
for i in 1 : 20
    if rand() < 0.5
        push!(numbers, rand(Uniform(1,4)))
    else
        push!(numbers, rand(Uniform(6,10)))
    end
end
```

You can also do a mixture:

`D = MixtureModel([Uniform(1,4), Uniform(6,10)], Categorical([0.5,0.5]))
rand(D, 1, 20)`

Here you have to specify a probability distribution over which uniform distribution to select from, hence the `Categorical`. The code above samples from each uniform range with equal probability. You can adjust the weighting by changing the Categorical as you see fit.

Comment: Hmmmm, I was just about to ask the OP a question about the desired distribution.  This solution is biased towards the <1,4> range, yes?

Comment: what if the 2 ranges are not the same length?

Comment: Just adjust your mixture values. This would mean changing rand() < 0.5 or changing the Categorical distribution as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Using a mixture model of two uniform distributions

`rand(MixtureModel(Uniform[Uniform(1,4),Uniform(6,10)]),1,20)`

edit :: this sampling is only correct if the size of the intervals is equal!

hth!

Comment: See my answer for why this might be dangerous. For example running: `mean(rand(MixtureModel(Uniform[Uniform(0,9),Uniform(9,10)]),1000))` I get a number around 7. Where you would expect to see a number around 5!